# How does a scanner work

Tags: receiver

I was reading [What is the difference between radio scanner and receiver?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/what-is-the-difference-between-radio-scanner-and-receiver) and I saw that it said that the scanner continues on scanning after a radio transmission is over.

If I find a frequency that I want to listen to, can I tell the scanner to stay put even after the transmission ends?

If that is the case, then what becomes the difference between a scanner and a receiver with a "scanning" feature?

Comment: As the answer you link says, "However, scanning is also an incidental feature on many digitally controlled receivers or transceivers, including those used by amateur radio operators"

Comment: I've voted to close this question as duplicate, because I believe it is essentially asking for clarification of the existing question's answer. I have also edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A scanner is simply a receiver that has the ability to automatically scan frequencies. Most transceivers and receivers have this feature. For example, your car stereo can likely scan for stations, but you can also manually tune the receiver with the knob.

Transceivers and receivers that are not "scanners" would have only a tune knob that you must manually control to change frequencies.

Also, yes, you can stop a scanner if you wish to continue to listen to a specific frequency.

Answer (score -1):

A Scanner is a basically a receiver with extra bells and whistles. It can automatically scan frequencies and stop at a busy one, and it can be programmed with your favorite public service frequencies. Think of it a wide range receiver with scanning and memory functions. See also: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_%28radio%29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_%28radio%29%20%22Scanner(radio)%20Wikipedia) and [http://www.radioreference.com](http://radioreference.com)